# I am getting External ID not found error

Tags: odoo-8

```
ParseError: "External ID not found in the system: hr_contract.hr_hr_employee_view_form2" while parsing /opt/openerp/odoo/FMPay-Devlopment--master/hr_extended/hr_extended_view.xml:688, near
<record id="view_employee_rate_inherited_form" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">employee.inherited.rate.form</field>
            <field name="model">hr.employee</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr_contract.hr_hr_employee_view_form2"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//group[@string='Contract']/field[@name='medic_exam']" position="before">
                        <field name="employee_type"/> 
                        <field name="reg_rate"/>
                </xpath>enter code here
            </field>
        </record>
```

This is my code. I am getting this error. I don't know that where I have to check.

Answer (score 0):

Please Check in __openerp_.p file

> in 'depends': ['base','hr','hr_contract'],

Answer (score 0):

To refer any view ID which is defined in another module, you should have a dependency on that module.

Please specify it in the **openerp**.py file as the value of depends key

```
    {
      #all other things goes here

    'depends': [
          ####
          'hr_contract',
          ####
         ],

      #all other things goes here
   }
```